# Mongoose find() with function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find an object in my collection which satisfies the following:
getDistance(userDefinedPosition, positionFromDocument) == true.

So I would like to do something like this

```
Users.find( getDistance(userDefinedPosition, positionFromDocument) == true, function( ... ) )
```

So userDefinedPosition is value while positionFromDocument is a field from inside a possible match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Users.$where(getDistance(userDefinedPosition, this.positionFromDocument)).exec(function( ... ))
```

See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html